# Background animated image

Tags: android, android-animation

I am wondering how I can do the following. I want my app background to be animated (let's say birds flying sort of what live wall papers look like). Is this usually done using GIF background or do I need to code animation or use paint/draw functionality to draw animations (I hope not!)

Any pointer is appreciated as I am not sure how to do that

Thank you

Comment: Does it help you? http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android/

Comment: Thanks but this talk about how to create wall paper. I am more interested in how these animated backgrounds are done in the first place. Our draw a bird programmatically? Or use images or use GIF or maybe a special drawing tool?

Comment: How long do you plan your clip to be? And does it have do be fullscreen or is only parts of it animated?

Comment: It's going to be infinite cycle (bird going across screen and coming back) and it is full-screen

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by using GIF image also, but first convert that GIF to frames

in xml

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/img1"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:text="submit"
     />
```

in java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gif);

    AnimationDrawable pro = (AnimationDrawable)i.getBackground();
    pro.start();
}   
}
```

in drawable create animation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">  
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame0" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="50" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame6" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame7" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame8" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame8" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame9" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame10" android:duration="50" />

</animation-list>
```

Hope this might help you

Comment: you have your images in drawable folder and gif animation file in drawable