# swipe animation on the activity background

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity, background

I want to write an application in which the background within the same activity undergoes a swipe animation. I tried using overwritePendingTransistion ([android left to right animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)) but that only works when going from one activity to the next activity... How can I put an swipe animation (for example left to right) on the background within the same activity? Please help

Thanks!

Comment: I think you may have to do that manually by storing the frames of your animation as drawables and then defining those frames. Here are a few links... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468425/android-activity-background-drawable-animated, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929681/background-animated-image

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html about Animations. Every `View` can be animated. Choose one of the various `Animator`s or set an `Animation` directly.